# Upload file from iphone using SFTP protocol

Tags: iphone, file-upload, sftp

I have one audio file captured from my iphone. I want to upload this audio file using SFTP protocol?

Is is possible? Is there any third party library available? Is it the same as putting file on FTP?

Comment: does anyone know about any method to put files on SFTP from iphone?

Comment: A later duplicate has some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979184/file-transfer-over-the-air-with-ipad/13927883#13927883

Comment: @Jim Did you upload file from SFTP protocol? if yes how did you do it?i want to do the same thing please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple has a tech note on this subject.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2009/tn2152.html#SECFILETRANSFERPROTOCOLS

The following section discuses support for file transfer. 
Note: There have been numerous attempts to make a secure 'FTP'.
These include:
FTPS — This is FTP over TLS. It is not supported by any built-in APIs on iPhone OS or Mac OS X.
SFTP — This is a new file transfer protocol based on SSH. There are no SSH APIs built in to either iPhone OS or Mac OS X. On Mac OS X you can access SSH functionality by sublaunching various command line tools. This is not an option on iPhone OS.

Answer (score 1):

The SFTP and FTP are completely different protocols.

Basically, there are the following file transfer protocols around:

- **FTP** – the plain old FTP protocol that has been around since 1970s. The acronym stands for "File Transfer Protocol". It usually runs over TCP port 21.
- **SFTP** – another, completely different file transfer protocol that has nothing to do with FTP. SFTP runs over an SSH session, usually on TCP port 22. It has been around since late 1990s. The acronym actually stands for "SSH File Transfer Protocol".
- **FTPS** or **FTP/SSL** - the plain, old FTP protocol run over TLS/SSL secure communication channel. FTP and FTPS relation is the same as HTTP and HTTPS relation to each other.
- **Secure FTP** - depends on context. Sometimes means FTPS, sometimes SFTP.

Comment: Thanks for sharing information on this. Have you any idea how file uploading works with SFTP? Have you any idea how it works with iPhone?