# Downloading/Uploading a file from a sftp server on the iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, sftp, scp, iphone-sdk-4.1

I need to connect to a sftp/scp server download a file, edit it and then reupload it.

As far as i know the SKD itself doesn't give you the ability for secure connections via ftp.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm looking for an option as well, preferably without cross-compiling OpenSSL and having to interface with it in plain C.

Comment: Maybe something like ConnectionKit, but afaik that doesnt work on the iPhone as its Cocoa-based?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131619/upload-file-from-iphone-using-sftp-protocol

Comment: I have seen that thread already, however it only discusses what the protocol is - and isn't. No real solution in there as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There we go: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ssh-sftp-objc.asp

Does everything and a bit more. It's commercial but it doesn't really matter in our case as developing our own libssl2 wrapper would take weeks and weeks.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/karelia/libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper

I have not tried it (yet...), but it's from the same person who made ConnectionKit. It's SFTP (I'm not sure if they mean secure ftp or ssh file transfer protocol)