# File transfer over the air with iPad

Tags: objective-c, c, ftp, sftp, file-sharing

I have an iPad app that outputs a PDF file that needs to be uploaded to a remote server. What are my options here? Is there a sFTP or FTP implementation for iOS that would help me achieve this? Can it be done using other protocol?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FTP Client Wrapper in Objective-C for iPhone](https://github.com/jkichline/ACFTP)

[ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit) (might not be iOS compatible)

Answer (score 0):

How about HTTP?  http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload

EDIT:
SCP using libssh2? http://www.libssh2.org/examples/scp_write.html

Comment: would love to use http but unfortunately I can't use an http server for the job, sorry I didn't specify in the question. I guess what I really need is a sFTP or FTP library.

Answer (score 0):

This on costs money: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ssh-sftp-objc.asp

Haven't tried it myself yet.

(And a duplicate on SO: [Upload file from iphone using SFTP protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131619/upload-file-from-iphone-using-sftp-protocol))